# What is "Circuit Breaker is open. Execution was short circuited." And How to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fiddler

I'm now making a simple loadbalance test, codes like this following:

```
public static class APIStoreLoadBalancerManager
    {

        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILoadBalancer> _balancers
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILoadBalancer>();

        private static volatile ManualResetEventSlim _switch = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);

        static APIStoreLoadBalancerManager()
        {
            AutoUpdateUrlMappings();
        }

        public static string ChooseServer(string key)
        {
            string choosenServerHost = null;

            _switch.Wait();

            ILoadBalancer bl = _balancers.GetOrAdd(key, (k) =>
            {
                return new BaseLoadBalancer(ConfigServiceInteraction.GetServiceURLs(k).Split(','), key, null);
            });

            choosenServerHost = bl.ChooseServer(key);

            return choosenServerHost;
        }

        public static void UpdateServerList(string key, IEnumerable<string> serverList)
        {
            ILoadBalancer old = null;
            if (_balancers.TryGetValue(key, out old))
            {
                _balancers[key] = new BaseLoadBalancer(serverList, key, old.Rule);
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateAll()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> list = null;

            foreach (string key in _balancers.Keys)
            {
                try
                {
                    list = ConfigServiceInteraction.GetServiceURLs(key).Split(',');
                    UpdateServerList(key, list);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\Error.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                    {
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                        sw.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                        sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        sw.WriteLine("================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private static void AutoUpdateUrlMappings()
        {
            Thread thAutoRefresh = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep((int)(AppSettings.AutoRefreshMinutes * 60 * 1000));
                    _switch.Reset();
                    UpdateAll();
                    _switch.Set();
                }

            });
            thAutoRefresh.IsBackground = true;
            thAutoRefresh.Start();
        }
    }
```

And now we can simple call like this:

```
context.RealUrl = APIStoreLoadBalancerManager.ChooseServer("xxx"); //this is a whole global WebApi.
```

And now I tested with fiddler manunally, and the result is:

[image]

Now it seems that after 1 minute (auto-update LOAD BALANCER's ip addresses for service...,ect). And it tells me:

[image]

Why and how to fix such an error? And I caught nothing in the Global's Application_Error (written in file).

Notice: *Plz ignore 200 and 502 (they appear alternatively, this is right according to my loadbalancer's algorithm).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is used through something like Hystrix.